# Inserting data into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

So I have a question about inserting data into a table, here's the question:

```
Assume a database table: customers

Assume these columns

name     varchar(10)

streetAddress     varchar)15)

stateAbbreviation     varchar(2)

balance     decimal(6,2)

Write the SQL that will insert a record to the customers table with these values:

name:     Jimmy

streetAddress:     10 Main St.

stateAbbreviation:     KS

balance:     17.56
```

Here is the code that I have come up with:

```
insert into customers (name,streetAddress,stateAbbreviation,balance) values ('Jimmy','10 Main St.','KS','17.56');
```

I'm getting an error saying that it's not right, what am I not doing right? Thanks

Comment: Surely there's a more useful error message somewhere than "it's not right"...

Answer (score 0):

The `balance` column is a `decimal`, but you're trying to insert a *string* value:

```
'17.56'
```

Instead, insert a numeric value:

```
17.56
```